# JQuery Get selected value from dynamically generated dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have an Dropdown list which is generated **dynamically**

the below is the code snippet of the Dropdown generated

```
<select class='selectAggregate'>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Min</option>
  <option>All</option>
</select>
```

How can i get the Seleceted option using JQuery

**Edit** I added the jquery code I have used

```
 $('.selectAggregate').each(function()
            {
                var $val = $("option:selected",this).text();                    
        }
```

`selectAggregate` is the class attribute of dynamically generated  dropdowns

Comment: Show us how you've tried `$('.selectAggregate').val()`

Comment: `'var $val = $("option:selected",this).val();`  using `this'`for current element

Comment: better you add value attribute to your option tags then try the same

Comment: tried adding value and also used `text()` to get

Comment: `$('.class').each(function(){ var $val = $("option:selected",this).val(); });` `.class` is the class value of dropdown list

Comment: I edited the Question with the code

Answer (score 8):

**Based on assumptions that you are using "direct" binding** which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on('change', ".selectAggregate", function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: Yes you get my point :). But i need to get the selected value inside a function

Comment: This method still won't work for any dynamically generated dom object, even if you manually invoke a change event. The in-memory changes you made are still inaccessible.  Anyone have a real working solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $.each($(".selectAggregate option:selected"), function(){            
           var $val = $(this).text();

        });
    });
```

Comment: _select do not have a value_ if this happens then text is evaluated as value.

Comment: Then you will need to Provide your code that you have tried here so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Edited my answer above based on your updated question, Refer : http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-get-selected-options-values-from-multiple-select-box

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change','.selectAggregate', function() {
var temp = $('.selectAggregate').children(":selected").text();
});
```

This will help you out, here you can get the value of dynamically generated select.
the change event is used because the element inside select (option) is being generated dynamically.

Comment: This will not work for dynamically created select elements, unfortunately. The event won't fire unless you make a selection with your mouse (does not fire if creating an option programmatically!).

Answer (score -1):

To get selected value you can use following statement in your js file.

```
$(".selectAggregate option:selected").val();
```

Comment: This answer does not take into account the event `change`